# UICollectionViewCell, multiple cell size, set gradientView width not set to the current cell size and sometimes changes when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i have 2 sizes for the cells in this class and that got me in a alot of troubles since i have to set bottom gradientView to the cell.
When  i first open the viewController every thing is set right except sometimes the gradient view colors doesn't look the same in some cells, but the real problem begin when you start scrolling, the bottom gradient view cut in half in the big cells and the gradientColors got really missy as u see in the image below some has really dark color as the bottom color and some has yellowish color instead which make the cells don't look the same

**How i setup the cell size :**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchProductsCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchProductsCell
    cell.configCell(data: data[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let smallCellSize : CGFloat =  self.collectionView.frame.height  / 2.11
    let height = indexPath.row % 3 == 0 ? self.collectionView.frame.height  : smallCellSize
     return CGSize(width: height, height: height)
}
```

**and that's the cell class setup :**

```
 class SearchProductsCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageV: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!

var isGradientAdded = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
}


func configCell(data : Product_Data ) {

    let img = data.image == "" ? data.thumb : data.image
    imageV.setupApiImage(imagePath: img)
    titleLbl.text = data.name
    if isGradientAdded == false {
        addGradient()
        isGradientAdded = true
    }
}

func addGradient () {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    let topColor = UIColor.yellow
    let botomColor = UIColor.red
    gradient.colors = [topColor.cgColor, botomColor.cgColor]
    gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
} 

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of cell reuse, your `gradient` `frame` will become out of date anytime the cell geometry changes.

In your `SearchProductsCell` class, update the `frame` of your `gradient` in an `override` of `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if isGradientAdded {
        gradientView.layer.sublayers?.first?.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to set `isGradientAdded = false` in `prepareForReuse`; if not, the gradient bounds won't change when a cell is reused

Comment: First thank you very much it worked like charm, but can i ask about the logic behind it ,does it mean when the cell size changes the layoutSubviews get called or does  it get called every time the cell dequeued.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` will get called anytime the cell size changes. So, this would help if the cell size changed because you rotated the device to landscape and the cells reconfigured.  It will get called when the cell is reused if that reuse causes the cell size to change.